# ¿Cómo hacer funcionar evento SelectedIndexChanged con AutoPostBack=false? DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlist

quisiera me pudieran ayudar a usar un dropdownlist, y su evento SelectedIndexChanged, pero con la opción de AutoPostBack=false, porque cuando está en true me recarga toda la página, aquí está mi código, he intentado algunas cosas pero no he podido, cuando selecciono un item de la dropdownlist, no pasa nada.

ASP

```
<div class="form-control">
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsuarios" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="700px" CssClass="form-control-solid text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlUsuarios" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
```

y C#

```
   protected void ddlUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                NombreLista = ddlUsuarios.SelectedItem.Text;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + NombreLista + "');", true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
        }
```

Comment: Has intentado verificar si es un postback para si no cargar los datos nuevamente?

Comment: Cuando dices "me recarga toda la página", ¿No está considerando el `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: @Davlio el update panel es con Ajax ¿verdad? intentaré. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres evitar recargar datos innecesarios cuando haga PostBack, puedes verificar si es un PostBack utilizando la propiedad [`IsPostBack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx).

Por ejemplo:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(IsPostBack == false)
   {
       //Cargar datos
   }
}
```

Entonces como el evento Change envia un PostBack, los datos no se cargaran de nuevo.